# CAML Query with multiple properties

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, javascript, caml-query

I want to use CAML query to delete elements from a SharePoint list.

Right now it deletes element if they have a specific text in their title:

```
camlQuery.set_viewXml('<View><Query><Where><Eq><FieldRef Name=\'Title\'/>' +
        '<Value Type=\'Text\'>'+statID+'</Value></Eq></Where></Query></View>');
```

What does one have to add to the camlQuery above when it should delete elements if they have a specific text in a column `playerID`? (So, the element should have a specific title and a specific playerID)

I tried different things, but can't seem to figure it out. Can someone help me?

Comment: What is the internal name and data type of your playerID field?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming `playerID` field is of type Single Line of Text (If data type is different then let me know. I will change query accordingly),

Try your query in below format:

```
<View>
    <Query>
        <Where>
            <And>
                <Eq>
                    <FieldRef Name='Title'/>
                    <Value Type='Text'>statID</Value>
                </Eq>
                <Eq>
                    <FieldRef Name='playerID'/>
                    <Value Type='Text'>playerID</Value>
                </Eq>
            </And>
        </Where>
    </Query>
</View>
```

**Note**: You need to use the [internal name](https://ganeshsanapblogs.wordpress.com/2023/04/17/how-to-find-the-internal-name-of-sharepoint-columns/) of your column in place of `playerID` at the line `<FieldRef Name='playerID'/>`.

**Reference**: [And Element (Query)](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/sharepoint-2010/ms196939(v=office.14)).